# ZeroDivisionError

Tags: python

```
from turtle import*
speed(200)
a=['blue','green','orange','red']


for e in range(2,150,2):
    for b in range(4):
        c=4%b
        d=color(a[c])
        forward(e)
        left(90)
```

error is -->  c=4%b ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Comment: Inner `range` starts with `0`. What is the `c = 4 % b` supposed to do anyway? If you want to cycle the colors, just do `c = b`.

Comment: `for b in range(4)` means start from 0 so the first b will be a zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range(4)` creates a range of number from `0` to `3` (inclusive).

The modulo operator `%` is a division operator.

And you can't divide by zero, which will happen with `c=4%b` in the first loop.

Comment: so what should i do?? i want a list starts with 0

Comment: @dianaabyaneh Depends on what you _want_ to do. If I'd have to guess, either just do `c = b` without the `%`, or remove the inner loop and do `c = e % 4` to cycle through the colors. In fact, probably remove the inner loop and then `c=e//2 %4` because the `range` has `step=2`